# C language: difference between x+1 and x++ in recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion

My teacher asked to write a program that prints the power of each array element using recursive function.

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void pow(int a[10],int i);

main()
{
    int a[10],i,c=0;
   printf("Enter 10 numbers:\n");
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
   printf("Power of elements in array:\n");
   pow(a,c);
   getch();
}

void pow(int a[10],int i)
{
    if(i!=10)
   {
    printf("%d\n",a[i]*a[i]);
      pow(a,i+1);
   }
}
```

Up to here, I had no problems.But when I changed the third last line  `pow(a,i+1)` to  `pow(a,i++)` 
the output was an infinite number of ones.

Can anyone please explain me why it ended up like this?
What exactly happened when I changed i+1 to i++?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should ask your teacher why they are teaching you to use an old version of the C standard.

Comment: Lol , I don't know why you want to increment `i` , but if you want to have fun try this `pow(a,++i)` instead of `pow(a,i++)` . Here you can understand much better the difference between `i++` and `++i` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two increment operators in C: one of which is postfix or postincrement operator as for example

```
i++
```

and other is unary operator or preincrement operator as for example

```
 ++i
```

The value of an expression of postincrement operator is the value of the operand **before its increment**. Thus this call

```
pow(a,i++);
```

is equivalent to

```
pow(a,i), i = i + 1;
```

Instead of the postincrement operator you could use the preincrement operator

```
pow(a, ++i);
```

and you will get the expected result because the value of the operator is the value of its operand **after its increment**.

Take into account that main shall have return type `int`.

Also in general case your function is wrong. It can not be applied to any array because it uses magic number 10.

I would write the function the following way

```
void pow( int a[], int n )
{
    if ( n > 0 )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", a[0] * a[0] );
        pow( a + 1, n - 1 );
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
pow( a, 10 );
```

In this case it can be used with arrays that have different sizes.

Comment: I focused on 10 because the array size had to be 10.

Comment: @Yu_Jain I have understood this. Nevertheless the array itself can have 10 elements but it is always better to write generic functions.:)

Answer (score 1):

`i++` is called a **post-increment**, which returns `i` and increments it **afterwards**.

`i + 1` is a temporary which returns what it says, `i + 1`, but does **not** change the value of `i` itsself.

You change the value of `i`, which is only **local to the function**. Therefore, the value of `i` recursively passed to `pow()` is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

`pow(a, i+1)` is passing to the next recursive call the incremented value of `i`. `pow(a, i++)`, is using the **post-increment** notation, which is FIRST returning the value of `i` (non-incremented) and thus performing the recursive call with the same value of `i`, and only then incrementing it, but the incremented value is lost. So your recursion turns to be infinite, since every call is receiving the same value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you can regard `pow(a,i++)` as `pow(a,i); i=i+1;`

Answer (score -1):

```
x+1
```

is an expression equal to one plus the value of x.  x is not modifed

```
x++
```

changes the value of after it is evaluated

Comment: True, but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I guess I was focusing on the question in the the title and did indeed answer the question.   

Author is a student so I am less likely to tell them how to fix it.  Rather, I just answer the question (which I did)  and not provide more.   -- Just the professor in me.
A cheap downvote in my opinion.

Comment: There's often a disconnect between the title of the question and the actual content - it's important to try and answer the OP's actual underlying question (even if that involves a little guesswork) rather than being overly literal/pedantic, which may be "clever", but doesn't really help the OP.

Comment: There is  sense of answering philosophy that can be used when responding to students.  A pedantic answer was not the intention of my response.  Ideally, I think that when one identifies themself as a student, responses can be appropropriate.  The student did not show and understanding between + operator and the post increment operator and the difference was pointed out in my answer.  I agree with URI's post "Stackoverflow is a great resource, but it's not meant to replace a basic language reference book"

http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254433/should-i-send-students-to-stack-overflow

Comment: Something else that teachers always try (often in vain) to drum into students: always read the entire question first before attempting an answer. ;-)